# <Growl/Growl.h> file not found in xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, growl

I'm trying to add a growl notification to an application for the mac but keep getting an error. I think I've followed the instructions right but something is wrong.Here's what I did:

I downloaded the growl SDK, added the `Growl-WithInstaller.framework` with "copy items into destination folder" checked.

Then added the framework to the build phase as copy files and set the destination to "frameworks".

I used an empty file to make the the growl registration ticket and dragged it to the copy bundle resources build phase.

Finally I added the `GrowlApplicationBridgeDelegate` to the `@interface` and the `#import <Growl/Growl.h>` to the header file.

When I build it I get an error saying that the `Growl/Growl.h` file was not found. It's there but it seems xcode cant find it. I imagine it's because I linked it wrong, any idea what the problem is?

I've tried the growl website and general linking help topics but I haven't found a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I now used this method instead: accepted

  1. In the project navigator, select your project
  2. Select your target
  3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab
  4. Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
  5. Click the '+' button
  6. Select your framework
  7. (optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the 'Frameworks' group
and the no errors are made, though the notifications still aren't appearing. I think it might be that I'm not calling them properly, I'll try again tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link against the framework in your project build phases, not just copy the files.

> To include a framework in your Xcode
>   project, choose Project > Add to
>   Project and select the framework
>   directory. Alternatively, you can
>   control-click your project group and
>   choose Add Files > Existing Frameworks
>   from the contextual menu. When you add
>   an existing framework to your project,
>   Xcode asks you to associate it with
>   one or more targets in your project.
>   Once associated, Xcode automatically
>   links the framework against the
>   resulting executable.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html

Comment: I'm using xcode 4, the only option is "add files". Nothing specifically about them being frameworks, which is why I think the problem is in linking. XCode 4 doesn't ask to associate with targets but there must be a way of doing it manually.